# ZF2 Class not found on Production

Tags: class, zend-framework2, autoloader

I have a very strange problem. A factory that loads a Class is working on my Dev machine (OS X) but when i published to my production server then the class can not be find.

> Fatal error: Class 'Vendor\Model\Entity\Tickets\TicketsAttachmentsEntity' not found in /var/www/domain/moduleNew/Vendor/src/Vendor/Model/Table/TicketsAttachments/Factory/TicketsAttachmentsTableFactory.php on line 33

What I have tried:

1. Commit with and without the Vendor folder
2. Composer Update / Composer Install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost certainly a case sensitivity problem. Linux file systems are case sensitive, OS X is not. Make sure the case of the class name matches the filename and class definition.

Answer (score 0):

It was a CaseSensitive Problem, but i don't know why on OS X is the Filename correct and on the Linux is all lowercase:

- OS X -> TicketsAttachmentsEntity
- Linux -> Ticketsettachmentsentity